# How do I find different words that can be created depending on the user's input?

Tags: python

Im currently trying to make a program that asks the user for a word and then generates all the different words that can be created by combining the letters in various ways. The output needs to fit three requirements:

- The words that it returns need to be a combination of either all or some of the letters
- The middle character of the word has to be in every single word.
- The length of the words that it returns can't be less than 4.

So far I've managed to make it bring back words that contain the middle character but I'm struggling with how to make it only generate words that are a combination of the letters from the user's input.

```
word = input("Word: ").lower()
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word] # Here I try to split the word into a list where each character in the word is a string. So for example if the user's input is "Help", this will return ["H", "e", "l", "p"]


savedwords = [] # This list is where I will keep the words that uses all the 9 letters to create a word.

middle_char = word[(len(word)-1)//2:(len(word)+2)//2] # This is the calculation that I'm using to find the middle character of the given word.

count = 0 # I will have to print the amount of different words that could be found using the users input.

usedwords =[] # Here I have a list that keeps track of all the words that have already been printed, to make sure the words only appear once. 


line = None 

file = open("svenskaord.txt", "r") # This is the file I'm using (It's a swedish dictionary containing roughly 23000 words)
nonempty_lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in file if line != "\n"] 

# Below here is where I'm struggling (and probably somewhere else that I'm not aware of).

for line in nonempty_lines:
    if middle_char in line and line not in usedwords and len(line) > 4:
        print(line)
        usedwords.append(line)
        count += 1
        if len(line) == 9:
            savedwords.append(line)


file.close()
```

Comment: please take the time to format code properly. you can use backticks ``` so each line appears on its own.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thank you for the tip! First time posting, which I'm pretty sure you already noticed

Comment: @Eddie a good question. At least better than my first questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question once you realize that all combinations of the string are the permutations of the string.

The built-in module itertools has a method called permutations. To use it, you do `permutations("test string")`.

To combine this with list comprehensions, we get,

```
from itertools import permutations
word=[''.join(p) for p in permutations('ABC')]
```

To combine it with your code should be quite simple from here.

Comment: Thank you @chess_lover_6 , appreciate it. I'm going to try it out now, I'll let you know how it goes. Btw, I love chess as well, actually had to delete the chess.com app since I always ended up there when I was trying to study.

Comment: I tried to use the itertools and managed to create this program which takes the word and returns the different combinations of the letters in the word. But I can't manage to make it go through the text file that I have with all the words. And sorry for structuring the code weirdly, I don't know how to make spaces```from itertools import permutations

word = input("Word: ").lower()
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

middle_char = word[(len(word)-1)//2:(len(word)+2)//2]

letters = list(word)

variations = permutations(letters)

for v in variations:
    print(v)```

Comment: same buddy. Same

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a master dictionary out of your list of possible words where the words are grouped by their distincts letters and have an associated Counter() object for the letter counts:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("svenskaord.txt", "r") as file:
    words = dict()                        # { MidLetter:(word,LetterCounts) }
    for w in map(str.strip,file):
        if len(w)<4: continue
        for letter in set(w):
            words.setdefault(letter,[]).append((w,Counter(w)))
```

From that dictionary you can quickly find the subset of eligible words that contain the middle letter of the user's word. Then select the words that can be formed with the letters of the user's word.  This strategy should be more efficient than generating permutation of letters from the user's word. For example: a user's 9 letter word would produce 46,224 permutations (of 4, 5, ... 8 letters). Comparatively, this sequential checks against the subset of words containing the middle letter would process 30% or less of the 23,000 words from the file (roughly 7,000 words).

```
word         = input("Word: ").lower()
counts       = Counter(word)
middleLetter = word[(len(word)-1)//2]
validWords   = list()
for newWord,newCounts in words[middleLetter]:
    if (newCounts & counts) == newCounts: # newWord can be formed
       validWords.append(newWord)
```

or, more succinctly:

```
word        = input("Word: ").lower()
counts      = Counter(word)
validWords  = [w for w,c in words[word[(len(word)-1)//2]] if (c&counts)==c]
```

*validWords will contain all 4+ letter words from "svenskaord.txt" that can be formed using letters of the user's word and contain the middle letter of the user's word*

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and responding. The word combinations should be based off of the text file that I have in my code, the "svenskaord.txt", which contains all the words in my native language, Swedish. Is there any possible way to use the requirements that you provided to the text file? In my original question I used a for loop to create the requirements but I'm unsure if I can attach all the requirements in it. Thank you once again for helping, I appreciate it!

Comment: I misread the requirements (thought the middle letter needed to be in the same position). Fixed it, now all requirements are met.